# Creating a html table using nested JSON file

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON file named `info.json` which have personal info of 20 students, and I want to convert it to a `HTML` table.

This is just an example(info of just 1).This goes for 20 students.[This is HTML table headings only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlUAO.png).This is how I want my table 's layout.
I couldn 't give here what I tried due to some error. This is upto what I have tried.

```js
[{
  "student_name": "Shastri Mahesh",
  "date_of_birth": "03-02-2002",
  "parents": [{
    "father_name": "Shidharth Mahesh",
    "mother_name": "Suhana"
  }],
  "blood_group": "AB-",
  "email": "shastri.mahesh@outlook.com",
  "phone": [{
    "landline": 9812343541,
    "mobile": 908252123
  }],
  "address": [{
    "door_no": "3A",
    "street_name": "Shastri nagar",
    "place_name": "Delhi",
    "pin_code": 142342,
    "country": "India"
  }],
  "degree": [{
    "ug": true,
    "pg": true,
    "others": "PhD(English Hons.)"
  }]
}]

$(document).ready(function() {

  // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE 
  $.getJSON("info.json", function(data) {
    var student = '';

    // ITERATING THROUGH OBJECTS 
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {

      //CONSTRUCTION OF ROWS HAVING 
      // DATA FROM JSON OBJECT 
      student += '<tr>';
      student += '<td>' + value.student_name + '</td>';

      student += '<td>' + value.date_of_birth + '</td>';

      student += '<td>' + value.parents.father_name + '</td>';

      student += '<td>' + value.parents.mother_name + '</td>';

      student += '<td>' + value.blood_group + '</td>';

      student += '<td>' + value.email + ',' + '<br>' + value.phone.landline + ',' + value.phone.mobile + '</td>';

      student += '<td>' + value.address.door_no + ',' + value.address.street_name + ',' + value.address.place_name + ', <br>' + value.address.country + '-' + value.address.pin_code + '</td>';

      student += '<td>' + value.degree.ug + '</td>';

      student += '<td>' + value.degree.pg + '</td>';

      student += '<td>' + value.degree.others + '</td>';

      student += '</tr>';
    });

    //INSERTING ROWS INTO TABLE  
    $('#table').append(student);
  });
});
```

Comment: First step is reading that file into a javascript variable. Were you able to do that ? Also could you be more specific about what you tried and what was the problem (even in plain english) ?

Comment: Is The data for all students is in the same format as this one ?

Comment: Why so many nested arrays when they only contain one object each? Unusual structure

Comment: *"I couldn't give here what I tried due to some error."* But that is how this site works. You show what you tried and others help improve it. It's a not  free code writing service. Show us the code you tried

Comment: Yes format is same for all the students

Comment: @ShashankChaudhary have you tried anything so far like written any jQuery code so that we can follow that a bit and provide an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your current code is that you are not using nested array data at all in your `$.each` function. You have nested array like `degree` and `parent's name`

So you need either loop through them as well or simply access the `data` directly since the data `structure` is always same. In addition, you need simplify the `results` of your array by using `.html` and create `td's` for each `row` you have.

You need a table `heading` well which you have `shown` in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlUAO.png) but you are **not** appending any heading in your own `code` at all.

Lastly, you also need some `CSS` to make sure the table looks nice and in order - I have fixed up all your `code` and more dummy data to show its all working now. Run snippet below.

**Complete Working Demo:**

```js
var data = [{
  "student_name": "Always Helping",
  "date_of_birth": "03-02-2002",
  "parents": [{
    "father_name": "Foo",
    "mother_name": "Bar"
  }],
  "blood_group": "Always B +",
  "email": "foo@google.com.au",
  "phone": [{
    "landline": 9812343541,
    "mobile": 908252123
  }],
  "address": [{
    "door_no": "3A",
    "street_name": "Shastri nagar",
    "place_name": "Melbourne",
    "pin_code": 85000,
    "country": "Australia"
  }],
  "degree": [{
    "ug": true,
    "pg": true,
    "others": "PhD(IT Hons.)"
  }]
}, {
  "student_name": "Shastri Mahesh",
  "date_of_birth": "03-02-2002",
  "parents": [{
    "father_name": "Shidharth Mahesh",
    "mother_name": "Suhana"
  }],
  "blood_group": "AB-",
  "email": "shastri.mahesh@outlook.com",
  "phone": [{
    "landline": 9812343541,
    "mobile": 908252123
  }],
  "address": [{
    "door_no": "3A",
    "street_name": "Shastri nagar",
    "place_name": "Delhi",
    "pin_code": 142342,
    "country": "India"
  }],
  "degree": [{
    "ug": true,
    "pg": true,
    "others": "PhD(English Hons.)"
  }]
}]

let table = $('#table') //table variable

//Create table heading
table.append("<thead><td>Name</td><td>DOB</td><td>Father's Name</td><td>Mother's Name</td><td>Blood Group</td><td>Contact</td><td>Address</td><td>UG</td><td>PG</td><td>Others</thead></th>");

//Loop through the data
$.each(data, function(index, x) {
  let row = $('<tr>');
  row.append($('<td>').html(x.student_name));
  row.append($('<td>').html(x.date_of_birth));
  //Mother / father
  row.append($('<td>').html(x.parents[0].father_name));
  row.append($('<td>').html(x.parents[0].mother_name));
  row.append($('<td>').html(x.blood_group));
  //get landline [0] or mobile [1]
  row.append($('<td>').html(x.phone[0].landline));
  //Address
  $.each(x.address, function(index, o) {
    row.append($('<td>').html(o.door_no + ', ' + o.street_name +
      ', ' + o.place_name + ', ' + o.pin_code));
  })
  //Degree
  row.append($('<td>').html(x.degree[0].ug));
  row.append($('<td>').html(x.degree[0].pg));
  row.append($('<td>').html(x.degree[0].others));
  table.append(row) //append all data
})
```

```css
th,
td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="table"></table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using Datatable you can refer to this example :[Nested object data (arrays)](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects_subarrays.html)